# "Shut down" takes me to greeter now?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, login-screen

**UPDATE - Removing my USB wifi dongle seems to cure the problem. So does disabling networking (but not disabling wifi alone). Now what?**
<s>**UPDATE 2 - The 'uptime' command says there are 2 users logged in. This will surely cause the behaviour I'm describing. I'm going to dig around and see if I can determine who the other user is.**</s> Nevermind, this was only due to the terminal I had open on the desktop.

If I log in to any account, choosing 'shut down' or restart takes me to the greeter. The same happens in the greeter itself - I am left there. No other users are logged in.

If I *don't* log in to an account after rebooting, the restart and shut down menu options in the greeter will work if I choose them *immediately* after the greeter appears. See a bootchart of this here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufb7s6ykvlbkjxj/jarlath-EP35-DS3-precise-20130116-3.png

If I wait 5 seconds or log in to a user account - they won't work. I've tested this several times. See a bootchart of this (logged in as user): https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx6jgoo2c7fy6pp/jarlath-EP35-DS3-precise-20130116-4.png

sudo -halt and sudo reboot both work as they should however.

I've output all processes from a logged in account (ps -A) and left them here: www.pastebin.com/e3WHtHYm

I assume that either an update, something new from the software center (not likely as I didn't install anything at the time) or a terminal command I issued is causing this. Here's my .bash_history from way before the problem began: pastebin.com/1DE5Tcd3

My kernel is 3.2.0-35, I tried also booting older kernels:

- 3.2.0-32, 31, 30, 29, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22 -> No difference

As per suggestions in bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792 I tried:

- Greped my /etc/init.d for services using su and removed 1 (ClamAV).
- Killed PulseAudio

Neither of these helped. Some more context below;

```
    jarlath@jarlath-EP35-DS3:~$ cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf 
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
jarlath@jarlath-EP35-DS3:~$ groups
jarlath adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers movies
```

**From Logviewer, here is the output that is generated at the time I try to shutdown from the user menu:**

```
auth.log
Feb 28 15:39:01 jarlath-EP35-DS3 CRON[15249]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 15:39:01 jarlath-EP35-DS3 CRON[15249]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 15:39:16 jarlath-EP35-DS3 polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session6 (system bus name :1.114, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Feb 28 15:39:19 jarlath-EP35-DS3 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user jarlath
Feb 28 15:39:22 jarlath-EP35-DS3 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Feb 28 15:39:22 jarlath-EP35-DS3 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Feb 28 15:39:25 jarlath-EP35-DS3 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "jarlath"
Feb 28 15:39:26 jarlath-EP35-DS3 dbus[580]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.184" (uid=104 pid=15385 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.15" (uid=0 pid=1438 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Feb 28 15:39:30 jarlath-EP35-DS3 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user lightdm
Feb 28 15:39:30 jarlath-EP35-DS3 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user jarlath by (uid=0)
Feb 28 15:39:30 jarlath-EP35-DS3 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Feb 28 15:39:34 jarlath-EP35-DS3 polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session9 (system bus name :1.198 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Feb 28 15:39:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 dbus[580]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.208" (uid=1000 pid=15640 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.15" (uid=0 pid=1438 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")


syslog
Feb 28 15:39:01 jarlath-EP35-DS3 CRON[15250]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Feb 28 15:39:16 jarlath-EP35-DS3 gnome-session[3479]: WARNING: Unable to load desktop file '/usr/bin/everpad.desktop': No such file or directory
Feb 28 15:39:16 jarlath-EP35-DS3 gnome-session[3479]: EggSMClient-WARNING: Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/everpad.desktop' has malformed Icon key 'everpad.png'(should not include extension)
Feb 28 15:39:16 jarlath-EP35-DS3 gnome-session[3479]: WARNING: Unable to find desktop file 'Transmission BitTorrent Client.desktop': Valid key file could not be found in search dirs
Feb 28 15:39:16 jarlath-EP35-DS3 gnome-session[3479]: WARNING: Unable to find desktop file 'gnome-Transmission BitTorrent Client.desktop': Valid key file could not be found in search dirs
Feb 28 15:39:18 jarlath-EP35-DS3 gnome-session[3479]: WARNING: Unable to stop system: Authorization is required
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:20 jarlath-EP35-DS3 NetworkManager[1173]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.126': no such name
Feb 28 15:39:21 jarlath-EP35-DS3 acpid: client 3292[0:0] has disconnected
Feb 28 15:39:21 jarlath-EP35-DS3 acpid: client 3292[0:0] has disconnected
Feb 28 15:39:21 jarlath-EP35-DS3 acpid: client connected from 15280[0:0]
Feb 28 15:39:21 jarlath-EP35-DS3 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Feb 28 15:39:22 jarlath-EP35-DS3 acpid: client connected from 15280[0:0]
Feb 28 15:39:22 jarlath-EP35-DS3 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Feb 28 15:39:26 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Successfully made thread 15412 of process 15412 (n/a) owned by '104' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb 28 15:39:26 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Successfully made thread 15416 of process 15412 (n/a) owned by '104' RT at priority 5.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Successfully made thread 15417 of process 15412 (n/a) owned by '104' RT at priority 5.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Supervising 9 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Successfully made thread 15418 of process 15412 (n/a) owned by '104' RT at priority 5.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Supervising 10 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Successfully made thread 15419 of process 15412 (n/a) owned by '104' RT at priority 5.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Supervising 11 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Successfully made thread 15420 of process 15412 (n/a) owned by '104' RT at priority 5.
Feb 28 15:39:27 jarlath-EP35-DS3 rtkit-daemon[2276]: Supervising 12 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 28 15:39:31 jarlath-EP35-DS3 gnome-session[15446]: EggSMClient-WARNING: Desktop file '/home/jarlath/.config/autostart/everpad.desktop' has malformed Icon key 'everpad.png'(should not include extension)
Feb 28 15:39:36 jarlath-EP35-DS3 goa[15570]: goa-daemon version 3.4.0 starting [main.c:112, main()]
Feb 28 15:40:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 dbus[580]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 15:40:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Feb 28 15:40:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Feb 28 15:40:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 dbus[580]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Feb 28 15:40:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit transaction
Feb 28 15:40:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/dcf18c7d7f2c412a82d3288c2df8c094
Feb 28 15:40:45 jarlath-EP35-DS3 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/dcf18c7d7f2c412a82d3288c2df8c094
Feb 28 15:40:46 jarlath-EP35-DS3 AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Get updates()
Feb 28 15:40:46 jarlath-EP35-DS3 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/dcf18c7d7f2c412a82d3288c2df8c094
```

**Solution:**
I have found a solution. I am not using it as an answer as it doesn't identify the root cause, but for others who are happy with just a solution for themselves they should try this advise from [grendndelman.net](https://www.grendelman.net/wp/policykit-adventures/)

Create a file named /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/usershutdown.pkla (the name must end in .pkla) and put the following in it:

```
[Allow Shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop-multiple-users
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow Restart]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart-multiple-users
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to the virtual terminal. Login and delete ~/.Xauthority

Comment: As which user though? It seems to be a userless problem.

Comment: Use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to tty1, then login as yourself, then delete the file. If your X session crashed, the old file will prevent you from starting and stopping X and cause the issue with shutdown. If that's the problem...

Comment: I just tried it but no effect. Thanks anyway. I also tried doing it for every user (except guest) but still no luck. It seems to be directly related to networking.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the `/etc/polkit-1/51-ubuntu-admin.conf` file and the output of the `groups` command.

Comment: Done Alex L. Interesting you ask about groups. I was messing with them around the time the issue began in an effort to give other users access to the "Movies" partition which was owned by the movies user.

Comment: Does the same happen when you do `sudo shutdown -h now` in virtual terminal / terminal ?? (save your work first) If it doesn't happen, how about using LogViewer you compare both behaviours?

Comment: sudo shutdown / halt / reboot work catalesia. I think something is starting during that five-second window after the greeter appears because I can shutdown via the GUI there if I'm quick enough. Thank you for introducing me to logviewer. I've appended the results above. I'm not sure what it means though.

Comment: Tell us about your dongle. What drivers are you using with it? Is this an NDISwrapper problem?

Comment: It's a plug-n-play, but I've removed it permanently and the problem persists.

Comment: Sadly, confirmed in 13.04 with no usb stuff attached.

Answer (score 1):

If more than one person is logged on pressing the shutdown button will take you to the greeter. You can still shut down with the command line with the command, `sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: True, but there is only one 'person' logged in. Whether there is something else logged in as a user (eg a service) I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo halt`. It would be interesting to find out if that, too sends you to the greeter.

Comment: sudo halt and sudo reboot work fine. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this might not be your problem, a good tip for anyone coming by having this issue:

I thought I was having the same problem:

**Turns out that "shutdown" doens't work if another session (SSH, ctrl-alt-f1, etc) is logged in.**

In my case, the first time this happened I had an SSH session open to check for temps, but from that point on it was always some sort of "now check what happens in the logs"-session, making the problem be very consistent.

Quiting all ssh/other logins made the shutdown work again.

Comment: I was aware of that, since ssh counts as another log-in. But it's good to point out.

Answer (score 0):

try to shutdown from terminal 
press ctrl + F1 then run sudo poweroff ,or just run sudo poweroff from terminal may this temporarily solve the problem

Comment: I have been doing that as a workaround - I could have mentioned it in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commands

> users

or

> w

to see if someone else is logged in somehow.

Comment: There is only one user logged in:
tenleftfingers consols - Fri19 4days -

Comment: Can you post the output from the "w" command. If it says you logged on at Fri19 and have been idle for 4 days. That might be part of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could force it. Make sure previous users LOG OUT instead of SWITCH USERS.